# HQL select when objects are mappedBy using annotations

Tags: java, orm, hql

I have one question about HQL. Supposing, I have two Tables. For example, Table "Person" and table "Mobile Number". One person many mobile numbers. Relation is `@OneToMany`.

In my Person.java class, which is entity I have some fields and one of the fields is

```
List<MobileNumber> mobiles; // (list of mobile numbers).
```

Problem is this :
I want to access in HQL one of the MobileNumber.java class's field. Like this :

```
Query = EntityManager.createQuery("select p.someField from Person where p.mobiles.someField = "value" );
```

MobileNumber object is mapped to Person object. As I mentioned relation is OneToMany and Person contains list of MobileNumbers. This is not problem if relation is OneToOne or ManyToOne because in this case Person object contains only one object of MobileNumber.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `JOIN` on the other entity

```
SELECT mobile.someField 
FROM Person person 
JOIN person.mobiles mobile 
WHERE mobile.someField = "value"
```

[Read more about it in the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e2678).

Comment: Thanks, but I am not using JOIN statement. Instead of this I use annotations.

Comment: @Chala You're using HQL. You need to use the proper HQL syntax to achieve your goal. This use case has nothing to do with the annotations.

Comment: Is it okay if I use annotations with this statement ?

Comment: @chala As I said, there is no notion of annotations for this particular use case. If you want to access the field of an entity that is mapped with `@OneToMany`, you need to use `JOIN`. I don't understand why you don't want to.

Comment: In addition , is only JOIN statement enough or it needs the type of join ?

Comment: @Chala When you only specify `JOIN`, it implicitly does an `INNER JOIN`. Read the linked documentation. It should all be there.

Comment: I have one more question. I have two objects: Group and Day. Day object is mapped to Group. In the Group entity annotation is @ManyToOne and this object contains Day object. I want to insert into database Group object but when I try this I got exception because in the method parameter in not Day object, it is Primary Key of Day table. What can I do ?

Comment: @Chala I recommend you post another question. I can't visualize it like this. And post your whole exception.

Comment: Can I write multiple joins  ? For example : SELECT mobile.someField 
FROM Person person 
JOIN person.mobiles mobile JOIN person.emails email
WHERE mobile.someField = "value" and email.someField = "value"

Comment: @Chala Yes, as long as those are mapped entities.

Comment: SELECT mobile.someField FROM Person person JOIN person.mobiles mobile JOIN person.emails email WHERE mobile.someField = "value" and email.someField = "value" is this syntax right ?

Comment: @Chala It seems right. The fields must have the same names as the fields in your entities.